# show div on button click with Lit component

Tags: javascript, components, web-component, lit

I have a Lit component. So the goal is when button is clicked I want to show a div with modal pop up window. How can I do that? here is my code:

```
    import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit';
    import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

    @customElement('my-form')
    export class CustomForm extends LitElement {

      @property()
 
      render() {
        return html`
        <div>
          <button @click="${this.showModalForm}">Open modal</button>
        </div>
        <div id="modalWindow" class="modalWindow"></div>
        `  
      }
    
      showModalForm() {
        console.log('clicked')
        
      }

    }
```

Comment: The standard HTML [<dialog> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) is probably easier

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working, how it fails, and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit';
    import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

    @customElement('my-form')
    export class CustomForm extends LitElement {

     static styles = css`
        .hide { display: none }
     `;

      render() {
        return html`
        <div>
          <button @click="${this.showModalForm}">Open modal</button>
        </div>
        <div id="modalWindow" class="modalWindow hide"></div>
        `  
      }
    
      showModalForm() {
        this.renderRoot.querySelector('#modalWindow').classList.toggle("hide");
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I add solution in vanilla js.

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit";
import { when } from "lit/directives/when.js";

export class CustomForm extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        showModalForm: { type: Boolean },
    };

    constructor() {
        this.showModalForm = false;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <div>
                <button @click="${() => (this.showModalForm = true)}">Open modal</button>
            </div>
            <!-- solution 1 : modal don't added in dom tree until click, lit will create later -->
            ${when(this.showModalForm, () => html`<div id="modalWindow" class="modalWindow"></div>`)}
            <!-- solution 2 : modal added in dom tree but hidden -->
            <div id="modalWindow" class="modalWindow" ?hidden=${!this.showModalForm}></div>
        `;
    }
   }
```